# Keep track execution plans on the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

We are still on SQL Server 2014, so we do not have query store.  Is there any other tool that can be used to track execution plan of stored procedures running on the server.

If a stored procedure timed out I should be able to check if the execution plan for a stored procedure changed.  How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can look at [OpenQueryStore](http://www.openquerystore.com) or a full monitoring and analysis solution like [SentryOne](https://sentryone.com).

Comment: Before there was Query Store there was the Management Data Warehouse. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/management-data-warehouse?view=sql-server-2017